# Recursive iteration over dynamically nested object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using angular JS and one of their examples:http://jsfiddle.net/furf/EJGHX/

I need to take the data when the update function occurs and add some values to it before I send to the server. (If doing this with angular instead of js would be better let me know)

I'm trying to get the 'parentid' and the 'index' and update the children.

**Here is the data I'm looping through**

```
{
    "children": [{
        "id": "5",
        "parentid": "0",
        "text": "Device Guides",
        "index": "1",
        "children": [{
            "id": "10",
            "index": "0",
            "text": "Grandstream GXP-21XX"
        }, {
            "id": "11",
            "index": "1",
            "text": "Polycom Soundstation/Soundpoint"
        }, {
            "id": "23",
            "index": "2",
            "text": "New Polycom"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "6",
        "parentid": "0",
        "text": "Pre-Sales Evaluation",
        "index": "0",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "7",
        "parentid": "0",
        "text": "Router Setup Guides",
        "index": "2",
        "children": [{
            "id": "9",
            "index": "0",
            "text": "Sonicwall"
        }, {
            "id": "12",
            "index": "1",
            "text": "Cisco"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "9",
        "parentid": "7",
        "text": "Sonicwall",
        "index": "0",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "10",
        "parentid": "5",
        "text": "Grandstream GXP-21XX",
        "index": "0",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "11",
        "parentid": "5",
        "text": "Polycom Soundstation/Soundpoint",
        "index": "1",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "12",
        "parentid": "7",
        "text": "Cisco",
        "index": "1",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "15",
        "parentid": "0",
        "text": "Post-Sales Implementation Check List",
        "index": "7",
        "children": [{
            "id": "16",
            "index": "0",
            "text": "Porting and New Number Details"
        }, {
            "id": "18",
            "index": "1",
            "text": "Partner Setup"
        }, {
            "id": "19",
            "index": "2",
            "text": "test"
        }, {
            "id": "21",
            "index": "3",
            "text": "test"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "16",
        "parentid": "15",
        "text": "Porting and New Number Details",
        "index": "0",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "18",
        "parentid": "15",
        "text": "Partner Setup",
        "index": "1",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "19",
        "parentid": "15",
        "text": "test",
        "index": "2",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "20",
        "parentid": "0",
        "text": "test",
        "index": "11",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "21",
        "parentid": "15",
        "text": "test",
        "index": "3",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "23",
        "parentid": "5",
        "text": "New Polycom",
        "index": "2",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "24",
        "parentid": "0",
        "text": "Test Markup",
        "index": "14",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": "25",
        "parentid": "0",
        "text": "test",
        "index": "15",
        "children": []
    }]
}
```

---

**This is how I'm currently looping through it, but it only gets the first dimension**

```
for (i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
    parentid = data[i].id == null ? '0' : data[i].id;
    data[i].index = i;
    if (data[i].children) {
        if (data[i].children.length > 0) {
            for (q = 0, r = data[i].children.length; q < r; q++) {
                data[i].children[q].parentid = parentid;
                data[i].children[q].index = q;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**I found this one on another fiddle, but I don't know how I would grab the parentid or the index**

```
$.each(target.children, function(key, val) { recursiveFunction(key, val) });

    function recursiveFunction(key, val) {
        actualFunction(key, val);
        var value = val['children'];
        if (value instanceof Object) {
            $.each(value, function(key, val) {
                recursiveFunction(key, val)
            });
        }

    }


function actualFunction(key, val) {}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want each 'child' to have a `parentID` (defined by its parent; `0` otherwise) and an `index` (based on its position within it sibling set).

```
function normalize(parent) {
    if (parent && parent.children) {
        for (var i = 0, l = parent.children.length; i < l; ++i) {
            var child = parent.children[i];
            child.index = i;
            if (!child.parentId) child.parentId = parent.id || '0';
            normalize(child);
        }
    }
}

normalize(data);
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. I tested it and I cant seem to get the parent id to set. Here is how it is integrated: http://jsfiddle.net/EJGHX/38/
Line 213, if you add a new child item and move it you'll see the result in the console.

Comment: @Stephen - I've had a quick look at the code in the example you provided, and it doesn't seem like any of the nodes have IDs associated with them. Where are you expecting this information to be set? At the moment, every `child.parentId` is being set to `'0'` because `parent.id` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Recursion is calling function inside the same function. Your sample is not a recursion at all;

```
function runRecursive(input) {
    for (var i = 0, l = input.length; i < l; i++) {
        var current = input[i];

        parentid = current.id == null ? '0' : current.id;
        current.index = i;
        if (current.children && current.children.length > 0) {
            runRecursive(current.children);
        };
    };
};

runRecursive(data.children);
```

Also you should define i and l with `var` keyword, otherwise it will be located in window context and recursion logic will broken.
Though I don't get what is `parentid` variable for and why it defined outside visible code.

Comment: Tommi, thank you for responding. If you look at Andrews answer, his is closer to what I'm looking for, I'm defining the parent id from the parent object's id.

Comment: Indeed. Don't forget to mark Andrew's answer for future users.