# Loop through JSON and print html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, wordpress

I have a JSON file with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    year: "2016",
    gallery: [
               {
                 folder_heading: "FOLDER 1",
                 folder_images: [
                                  {
                                   title: "TITLE 1",
                                   filename: "IMG_9225.jpg",
                                   url: "http://www.bioner.fi/assets/uploads/2016/08/IMG_9225.jpg",
                                   alt: "",
                                   caption: "",
                                   width: 1781,
                                   height: 2560,
                                   sizes: {
                                           gallery_thumbnail: "http://www.bioner.fi/assets/uploads/2016/08/IMG_9225-300x431.jpg",
                                           gallery_thumbnail-width: 300,
                                           gallery_thumbnail-height: 431
                                   }
                                 },
                                 {
                                   title: "TITLE 2",
                                   filename: "IMG_9225.jpg",
                                   url: "http://www.bioner.fi/assets/uploads/2016/08/IMG_9225.jpg",
                                   alt: "",
                                   caption: "",
                                   width: 1781,
                                   height: 2560,
                                   sizes: {
                                           gallery_thumbnail: "http://www.bioner.fi/assets/uploads/2016/08/IMG_9225-300x431.jpg",
                                           gallery_thumbnail-width: 300,
                                           gallery_thumbnail-height: 431
                                   }
                                 },             
                 ]
    ]
},
```

I did maintain to get year numbers and populate them to the list with jQuery's each function. But I would need to maintain this structure and print it in this way:

```
<!-- YEARS -->
<ul>
  <li>2016</li>
  <li>2015</li>
  ........
</ul>
<!-- GALLERY CONTENT WRAPPER -->
<section>
  <!-- 2016 -->
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>FOLDER 1</li>
      <li>FOLDER 2</li>
      <li>FOLDER 3</li>
      .........
    </ul>
    <!-- FOLDER 1 Images -->
    <div>
      <img />
      <img />
      <img />
      <img />
      .......
    <div>
    <!-- FOLDER 2 Images -->
    <div>
      <img />
      <img />
      <img />
      <img />
      .......
    <div>
   .............
  </div>
  <!-- 2015 -->
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>FOLDER 1</li>
      <li>FOLDER 2</li>
      <li>FOLDER 3</li>
      .........
    </ul>
    <!-- FOLDER 1 Images -->
    <div>
      <img />
      <img />
      <img />
      <img />
      .......
    <div>
    <!-- FOLDER 2 Images -->
    <div>
      <img />
      <img />
      <img />
      <img />
      .......
    <div>
   .............
  </div>
 ...................
</section
```

Should I go and try use jQuery with this or go with some other framework. Or is vanilla JS the most efficient way to achieve this. That's probably option based but I would need someone to point me in the right direction how to iterate my JSON array and print it in the HTML.

For this point I have done this with PHP in WordPress, but since there is a lot of images and folders my server takes a long time to process that (might be because I'm using ACF's get_field and get_subfield).

But now I want to try using WP-REST API for this task to get more familiar with it.

**How do I achieve this**, and which way faster way to query all the images from the database REAST-API + JS or ACF PHP?

---

**UPDATE:**
I did manage to get the JSON file and iterate the first list (years list) with the year numbers with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: 'url-to-json-file',
                  dataType: 'json',
                    error: function() {
                    alert( 'Unable to load tabs.' );
                  },
                  success: function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(i, item){
                      var int = i + 1,
                          tapahtumaTab = '<a href="#tapahtuma-' + int + '" data-toggle="tab"><h2>' + data[i].tapahtuman_nimi + '</h2></a>';

                      $('<li />', {html: tapahtumaTab}).appendTo('#years-list');

                    })
                  }
                });
              });
```

Comment: @guradio check the update

Answer (score 1):

**This example will help you to create dynamic elements. Append the output to a element.**

Your JSON Data is not proper, you can not give "-" in the keys. If you want to please use quotes.

```
    var data = [
    {
        "year": "2016",
        "gallery": [
            {
                folder_heading: "FOLDER 1",
                folder_images: [
                    {
                        title: "TITLE 1",
                        filename: "IMG_9225.jpg",
                        url: "http://www.bioner.fi/assets/uploads/2016/08/IMG_9225.jpg",
                        alt: "",
                        caption: "",
                        width: 1781,
                        height: 2560,
                        sizes: {
                            gallery_thumbnail: "http://www.bioner.fi/assets/uploads/2016/08/IMG_9225-300x431.jpg",
                            "gallery_thumbnail-width": 300,
                            "gallery_thumbnail-height": 431
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        title: "TITLE 2",
                        filename: "IMG_9225.jpg",
                        url: "http://www.bioner.fi/assets/uploads/2016/08/IMG_9225.jpg",
                        alt: "",
                        caption: "",
                        width: 1781,
                        height: 2560,
                        sizes: {
                            gallery_thumbnail: "http://www.bioner.fi/assets/uploads/2016/08/IMG_9225-300x431.jpg",
                            "gallery_thumbnail-width": 300,
                            "gallery_thumbnail-height": 431
                        }
                    },

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

var finalString = "<section>";
var yearList        = "<ul>";

for(var i in data) {
    var yearData = data[i];
  yearList += "<li>" + yearData['year'] + "</li>";

  var galaryData = data[i]['gallery'];
  var folderList = "<ul>";

  for(var j in galaryData) {
    folderList += "<li>" + galaryData[i]["folder_heading"] + "</li>";

    var imageData = galaryData[i]["folder_images"];
    var imgDiv = "<div>";
    for(var k in imageData ) {
        imgDiv += "<img />";
    }
    imgDiv += "</div>";
  }

  finalString += folderList + imgDiv;
}
yearList += "</ul>";

finalString += "</section>";


finalString = yearList + finalString;
console.log(finalString);
```

Comment: Helped me a lot, thanks! I had to go around the "-" key error, since I couldn't  find a way to edit in WordPress. My data comes from the WP REST API, so i did get it like this:  var galleryThumb = 'gallery_thumbnail'; var imageWidth = imageData[k]['sizes'][galleryThumb + '-width']; var imageHeight = imageData[k]['sizes'][galleryThumb + '-height']; So is there any problem getting string like this?

Answer (score 0):

Standard javascript is more than enough. Json is a Javascript object Notation is what it is. You should be able loop through all json elements with some recursive function like here: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061736/recursive-iteration-over-dynamically-nested-object-array)