# Traversing an object in javascript and convert it in specific format

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following object structure:

```
{
    a: {
        b: "abc",
        c: [
            {
                d: "pqr",
                e: true
            },
            {
                f: 1,
                e: ["xyz", 1]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I want to convert these structure in specific format that are shown in expected output.

I'm trying to traverse above structure but the constructed path not correct
Here is what I'm doing

```
const getFinalNode = function(data, path){
  if (typeof data === 'object'){
    for (let key in data) {
      // console.log(key);
      if (typeof data[key] === 'object'){
        path += key+'/'
        getFinalNode(data[key], path)
        // console.log(true);
      }else{
        console.log({
          value: data[key],
          key: key,
          path:path
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
getFinalNode(data, "");
```

My expected output should be

```
[
    {
        name: "b",
        value: "abc",
        path: "a/b"
    },
    {
        name: "d",
        value: "pqr",
        path: "a/c/0/d"
    },
    {
        name: "e",
        value: true,
        path: "a/c/0/e"
    },
    {
        name: "f",
        value: 1,
        path: "a/c/1/f"
    },
    {
        name: "e",
        value: 'xyz',
        path: "a/c/1/e"
    },
    {
        name: "e",
        value: 1,
        path: "a/c/1/e"
    }
]
```

So how can I traverse above structure and convert it in expected output or is there any solution that can I use in my existing code.

Now I getting following output

[image]

Comment: Take a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061736/recursive-iteration-over-dynamically-nested-object-array)

Comment: I'm curious as to why the second object in your array would have an expected path of `a/b/c/0/d`, instead of `a/c/0/d`? Neat question by the way. :-)

Comment: Shouldn't the array `e: ["xyz", 1]` be separated into two objects (like the array `c` is)?

Comment: What exactly is your question? and what does *constructed path not correct* mean?

Comment: @jeffdill2  update the question with correct path

Comment: @Liam  I have an above object and I want to convert this object just like my expected output

Comment: So you want us to debug your code for you?

Comment: @NIKHILRANE Can you please answer my question?

Comment: @Liam doesn't seem that way to me. The OP has provided his input, the expected output, and the code he's built to try to produce said output. The only thing that would be helpful here is to see what _incorrect_ output you're currently getting from the code you've built.

Comment: @ibrahim mahrir yes we can? update my question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mostly just needed to pass an array through and give a little adjustment to the path you're building.

The inclusion of the last item in the final path is a little surprising, and took some extra tweaking, but I think it's what you're looking for in the result.

```js
const getFinalNode = function(data, path, result){
  result = result || [];

  // This check isn't needed if the initial call will always be an object.
  if (typeof data === 'object'){ 
    for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(data)) {
      if (typeof val === 'object'){
        getFinalNode(val, path ? (path + "/" + key) : key, result);

      }else{
        const notNum = isNaN(key);
        result.push({
          name: notNum ? key : path.slice(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1),
          value: val,
          path:path + (notNum ? "/" + key : "")
        });
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const data = {
    a: {
        b: "abc",
        c: [
            {
                d: "pqr",
                e: true
            },
            {
                f: 1,
                e: ["xyz", 1]
            }
        ]
    }
};

console.log(getFinalNode(data, ""));
```

I used `Object.entries()` with destructuring assignment in a `for-of` just for the convenience of having the key and value assigned to variables. Your original `for-in` loop was fine too.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass both the `path` and the accumulated array `acc` to the recursive call of `getFinalNode`:

```js
const getFinalNode = function(data, acc = [], path = "") {         // default values for acc and path, so we won't bother ourselves with that
    for(let key in data) {                                         // for each key in the object/array data
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {                             // if this is an own property
            if(data[key] && typeof(data[key]) === "object") {      // if the value of the current property is an object/array (not null: typeof null === "object")
                getFinalNode(data[key], acc, path + "/" + key);    // then traverse it, passing acc to add to what we already have
            } else {                                               // otherwise
                acc.push({                                         // make a leaf object and push it to the accumulator acc
                    path: path.slice(1) + "/" + key,               // slice to remove the first "/" from path
                    name: key,
                    value: data[key]
                });
            }
        }
    }
    return acc;
}


let data = {"a":{"b":"abc","c":[{"d":"pqr","e":true},{"f":1,"e":["xyz",1]}]}};

let result = getFinalNode(data);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two things you are missing to get the expected output: 
 - You are not adding the path when data["key"] is not an object
 - You are looking for get an array output but you are printing every element separatedly.

Looking at you desired output i see the path always includes b, even when b and c are siblings, and that doesn´t allow have them both in the same path.Taking this as a typing mistake, I modified a bit the script in order to get the correct output:

```js
var data = {a: { b: "abc", c: [ { d: "pqr", e: true},{ f: 1, e: ["xyz", 1] }]}};

var output = [];

getFinalNode = function(data, path){
  if (typeof data === 'object'){
    for (let key in data) {
      // console.log(key);
        path.push(key)
        getFinalNode(data[key], path)

        // console.log(true);
        if (typeof data[key] != 'object'){ 
        output.push({
          value: data[key],
          key: key,
          path:path.join("/")
        });}      
    }
  }
  path.splice(-1,1) 
}

getFinalNode(data, []);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun, dirty solution, kids don't do that at home !

```js
function getFinalNode(node) {
  return (function rec(obj, path='', results=[]) {
    path = path && (path + '/')
    return Object.entries(obj)
      .reduce((arr, [name, value]) => void (typeof value === 'object'
          ? rec(value, path + name, arr)
          : arr.push({ name, value, path: path + name })) || arr,
        results)
  })(node)
}

console.log(getFinalNode({a:{b:"abc",c:[{d:"pqr",e:true},{f:1,e:["xyz",1]}]}}))
```

To explain a bit:

```
path = path && (path + '/')
```

If `path` is empty, the first part of the condition will be evaluated, so will get an empty string. Otherwise, the second part is evaluated, and we do the concatenation.

```
void (whatEverExpression) || arr
```

void will make whatEverExpression returning undefined, so `arr` will be returned instead.

(It's a trick, I find handful when reducing something. Even if ESLint forbid the use of void :D)

---

Edit: Inspired by rock star's answer, with `entries`, it's even better :D

Answer (score 0):

You could take a function for collecting the items and a function for a recursive call for iterating the object.

```js
function traverse(object) {

    function iter(o, p) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            if (o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
                return iter(o[k], p.concat(k));
            }
            result.push({ name: k, value: o[k], path: p.join('/') });
        });
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(object, []);
    return result;
}

var object = { a: { b: "abc", c: [{ d: "pqr", e: true }, { f: 1, e: ["xyz", 1] }] } };

console.log(traverse(object));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```